# What is his probability to win from one ticket?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If someone buy $260$ tickets such that to win with a ticket he needs to choose $6$ correct numbers from $42$ numbers.

What is his probability to win from one ticket?

Comment: In how many ways can you pick $6$ numbers from $42$?

Comment: @MattiP. $42 \choose 6$= 5245786

Comment: Good. Therefore, the probability of choosing the correct one from those is ...?

Comment: @MattiP. $\frac{6}{42}$ ?

Comment: No. If you have $5~245~786$ different cases, out of which one is correct, and you get to choose one, the probability that you choose the correct one is $\frac{1}{5~245~786}$.

Comment: @MattiP. Ok, and why then?

Comment: Remember that the probability is the number of favorable cases, which is $1$ in this case (the exact set of six numbers), divided by the number of cases in the sample space, which you correctly determined is $\binom{42}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the question "What is his probability to win from one ticket?" means "What is his probability to win from (at least, not exactly) one ticket?", otherwise it's not clear to me the reason of having 260 tickets and not only one.

In this case, the probability you look for is 1 minus the probability that there is no a winning ticket (among the 260 ones). Let $X_i$ be the Bernoulli random variable telling you whether or not you win with ticket $i$. Then, its success parameter is $p=1/{ 42 \choose 6 }$ and the $X_i$'s are assumed independent. So, you want to compute
$$
1-P(X_1=0 \cap\ldots \cap X_{260}=0) = 1 - \prod_{k=1}^{260} P(X_k=0) = 
1-(1-p)^{260}.
$$